# CAML Query Custom Ordering

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query, caml, ordering

I have looked around a bit, but have not found any reference to this particular issue.  Is it possible to specify a custom ordering in a CAML query?  What I mean by this is, say I have a list with a column that contains values 'Apple', 'Orange', and 'Grape', and I would like to create a CAML query that will group items by these values, order them within the groups and return the whole list ordered as ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Grape'].  Is there a way to specify such an ordering?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the `GroupBy` attribute in CAML query. Here is a link of how to format your caml to include the GroupBy statement:
http://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/caml-query-example-including-groupby/